# Passing client-side parameters to the server-side with React/redux and Express (EMPTY_RESPONSE error)

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, get

I would like to pass a variable from my client-side to my server-side with react/redux and express. In the example below I'm trying to pass the `VIEW_ID` value to make a google analytics API call. I've been trying to follow some examples given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108326/how-to-pass-client-side-parameters-to-the-server-side-in-angular-node-js-express). When launching my app and after a couple of minute waiting I've got the following error :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/gadata net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
dispatchXhrRequest @ bundle.js:34151xhrAdapter @ bundle.js:34003
bundle.js:31131  action @ 15:29:48.843 undefined
```

I guess I'm missing something on the google analytics API callback.

Here is my action where I'm passing the `VIEW_ID` as a second parameter in my `axios.get` method :

```
export const fetchgadata = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null
  });

var VIEW_ID = "ga:802840947";

return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gadata", VIEW_ID)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching: false,
            data: response.data.rows.map( ([x, y]) => ({ x, y }) )
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
            ype: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
      });
      console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });
};
```

and here the API call from my server file :

```
app.use('/gadata', function(req, res, next) {

var VIEW_ID = req.query.VIEW_ID; 

var key = require('./client_id.json');

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'], null);

var authorize = function( cb ) {
  jwtClient.authorize(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    } else {
      if ( typeof cb === "function") {
        cb();
      }
    }
  });
}
var queryData = function(req, res) {
  authorize(function() {
    analytics.data.ga.get({
      'auth': jwtClient,
      'ids': VIEW_ID,
      'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
      'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
      'max-results': 10,
    }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      res.send(response);
    }); 
  });
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMIIW, i don't think that's how you pass querystring through axios.
Try something like this (You can see the axios documentation here, https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

```
axios.get(url, {params: {VIEW_ID: VIEW_ID}})
//or this
axios.get(url + '?VIEW_ID=' + VIEW_ID)
```

Comment: yes thanks. you are totally right. I didn't understand how req and params were linked but now it's clearer !