# Pass data to nodejs server from javascript file - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been fighting with an (firebase & nodejs) issue and it's 4th part of that problem, How can i pass data after login to **server.js**

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108326/how-to-pass-client-side-parameters-to-the-server-side-in-angular-node-js-express) But failed to get it working.

Basically i am trying to send user **idToken** to server to get it verified.

This what i have tried:

```
const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function(){
    $('.load-bar').hide();
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        console.log(data);
        $http.get('server', {params: {idToken: idToken}})
            .success(
                function(success){
                    console.log('success');
                })
            .error(
                function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle error
    });
});
```

But it's doing nothing no error not success and on **server.js**

```
app.get('/server', function(req,res, next){
   console.log(req.query.idToken);
});
```

But still nothing. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `console.log(req.query.idToken);` called on the server and does it output something? If not is the `console.log(data)` called on the client? Is there an error reported at `// Handle error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't return `Promise` from `then`, the `Promise` will return `undefined`. And to resolve a promise with success you need to return `Promise.resolve` and to terminate with error you need to return `Promise.reject`. Try this -

```
const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function(){
    $('.load-bar').hide();
    return firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        console.log(data);
        $http.get('server', {params: {idToken: idToken}})
            .success(
                function(success){
                    return Promise.resolve(success);
                })
            .error(
                function(error){
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Error - `promise.reject` is not a function

Comment: @NomanAli Make sure you've used `Promise.reject` and not `promise.reject`.

Comment: with Promise is says in console `ReferenceError: $http is not defined`

Comment: @NomanAli Make sure you've imported libraries properly. If you're using `angularjs` you may need to inject `$http` service in your controller.

Comment: Sorry! i am using vanilla JS, not angular. :(

Comment: @NomanAli vanilla js does not have a `$http` library. If you want to use vanilla js you need to use `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149773/discussion-between-noman-ali-and-shawon191).

Answer (score 0):

Your route needs to respond:

```
app.get('/server', function(req,res, next){
  console.log(req.query.idToken);
  return res.send('success!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are not sending your response back to the api call origin. That is why you are not getting success or error results.

Change the code in server as:

```
app.get('/server', function(req, res, next){
   console.log(req.query.idToken);
   res.send(200);/*Just sends success code*/
   //res.send("Token rcvd");/*Or send some custom message back to call origin*/
});
```